# Horizontal ScrollView - xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, scrollview, xamarin.forms, content-pages

I know there are many about this topic ([Scroll horizontally in Xamarin.Forms ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24389661/scroll-horizontally-in-xamarin-forms-scrollview)), but I could not implement the horizontal scrollview which scrolls horizontally.

```
public class DetailView : ContentPage
{
    public DetailView ()
    {
        StackLayout stack = new StackLayout {
            Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
            };
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
            stack.Children.Add (new Button { Text = "Button" });
        var scrollView = new ScrollView
        {
            Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
            Content = stack
        };
        Content = scrollView;
    }   
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
public DetailView()
{
    var scrollableContent = new StackLayout()
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
        Children =
        {
            new BoxView(){HeightRequest=40, WidthRequest=40, BackgroundColor = Color.Red},
            new BoxView(){HeightRequest=40, WidthRequest=40, BackgroundColor = Color.Green},
            new BoxView(){HeightRequest=40, WidthRequest=40, BackgroundColor = Color.Blue},
            new BoxView(){HeightRequest=40, WidthRequest=40, BackgroundColor = Color.Maroon},
        }
    };

    Content = new ScrollView()
    {
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
        Content = scrollableContent,
    };
}
```